# Power BI and Excel Formulas

Tags: powerbi

I've a doubt, I have this table in Excel with these columns and formula, but I've to create them in POWER BI to see if the same formula works and not use Excel, I tried to use LOOKUPVALUES, RELATED and RELATEDTABLE in Power BI that are used as synonym of VLOOKUP in Excel, and it does not give me the same result as in Excel in power BI, I attach image of the columns in Excel with the formula, the columns are C and D, the column that was found in Excel and I want it in power BI is the E.

[Is in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIO0c.png)

I used LOOKUPVALUES, RELATED AND RELATEDTABLE, in power BI, I used the formulas to create the column and it just comes out blank.